# Karma.js installation in WebStorm - bash: karma: command not found

Tags: node.js, webstorm, karma-runner

So I have installed node.js from nodejs.org and I have installed karma.js in my project using the Webstorm command tool: npm install karma. I have also added those 3 path variables (please tell me which one I don't need) in Webstorm->Settings->Path Variables.

**Name**: nodejs 
**Value**: /usr/local/bin

**Name**: npm 
**Value**: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin

**Name**: karma 
**Value**: /Users/maxime/Documents/WebStorm/icms/node_modules/karma/bin

When I type init karma to get the karma config file, I get:
**bash: karma: command not found**

I search on the site for some answers, but all I found was to add those path variables...

EDIT: I tried with sudo but it does not work

EDIT: It works with /Users/maxime/Documents/WebStorm/icms-dev-39534/node_modules/karma/bin/karma init, but it's still not working with karma init.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The command line interface is in a separate package.

To install this use:

```
npm install -g karma-cli
```

Comment: Out of all other answers this is `The way` - it should be done !

Comment: Also required for the AngularJS 'up and running' book

Comment: I'm on windows 10 and I have the C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules in my path, but I cannot run karma or any other modules installed. Karma file in the bin folder has no extension. Anything that I install with npm -g flag ends up without extension. How does everyone execute these from cmd?

Answer (score 2):

Path variables have nothing to do with this problem, you can remove them all.

What you need is to [install karma module globally](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/).

Then ensure that `{prefix}/bin` is in the system `PATH` environment. If you don't install it globally, you will have to add `/Users/maxime/Documents/WebStorm/icms-dev-39534/node_modules/karma/bin/` to `PATH`.

Make sure to [read this answer carefully](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/51677) as setting environment variables on Mac is tricky. You may need to reboot for the `PATH` environment changes to have effect in WebStorm.

Answer (score 1):

I used:

npm install -g karma-cli

and under Users/{user}/AppData/Roaming/npm

added a karma.cmd command with the following content:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\karma\bin\karma" %*
) ELSE (
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\karma\bin\karma" %*
)
```